# Creating HTML Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a `multi-step` modal using [this example](https://www.ngzhian.com/multi-step-modal/) but I can't seem to make it dynamically using javascript.
I made `testCaseNames` hardcoded because those are fetched from ajax post.

Basically a 2 step modal where the first shows `teste1` in the title and body and the other the same but for `teste2`.

Is there a simpler way to do it? Even in this small code it's a mess to work with it. Why is my modal not working like the example?

```js
$('#btnSubmit').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var testCaseNames = ['teste1','teste2'];
  
  //Modal
  var modal = '<form class="modal multi-step" id="creationModal"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header">';
  //Progress
  modal += '<div class="m-progress"><div class="m-progress-bar-wrapper"><div class="m-progress-bar"></div><div class="m-progress-stats"><span class="m-progress-current"></span>/<span class="m-progress-total"></span></div><div class="m-progress-complete">Completed</div></div>';

  $.each(testCaseNames, function(key, value) {
 
        //Headers
        $('.modal-header').html('<h4 class="modal-title step-' + key + ' data-step="' + key + '"</h4>');
        //Body
        modal += '<div class="modal-body step-' + key + '" data-step="' + key + '">' + value + '</div>';
        // //Footer Buttons
        modal += '<div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div>';
        modal += '</div></div></form>';
  
  });
  $('#modalDiv').empty().html(modal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.ngzhian.com/multi-step-modal/multi-step-modal.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<button type="submit" class="btn btn-rounded btn-success-outline top10" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#creationModal" id="btnSubmit">Create</button>

<script>
  sendEvent = function(sel, step) {
    $(sel).trigger('next.m.' + step);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: where is you "modalDiv" define?

Comment: @RahulSahu sorry i forgot. it's just a clean div just to append the modal to the body

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is working code that needs a code review. ask on [codereview.se]

Comment: It's not working.... do you see it working?

Comment: <div id='modalDiv'></div> add this tag after or before submit button then your code is working

Answer (score 1):

Last line of your JQuery code - `$('#modalDiv').empty().html(modal);`, you trying to add new content to the div with id `modalDiv`, but this element is not at your HTML now, just add it and your code will work.